# How to realize the wordpress permalink function on an homemade php website

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, wordpress

I'm realizing a php website and I'm trying to split all the files in a way that should give me the possibility to update them easily.
In the current structure I've:

- header.php
- menu.php
- footer.php

These files are included in the following pages:

- page1.php
- page2.php
- page3.php

On each one of the pages above I write specific content. At the end my urls are:

> http://www.example.com/page1.php 
>   http://www.example.com/page2.php
>   http://www.example.com/page3.php

But what I would like to do is to reproduce the wordpress structure that uses index.php only as output.

So, just to go more in detail, I would like to realize an index.php inside of which I'll include just one time:

- header.php
- menu.php
- footer.php

and including the page1.php content, the page2.php content and the page3.php content. At the end I need to have as URL a permalink that says:

> http://www.example.com/page1 
>   http://www.example.com/page2
>   http://www.example.com/page3

I've checked on the web but seems there's nothing online useful for my needs and when I check "permalinks" users talk only of wordpress.
Could you help me please on this activity?
Tell me if my request is not so clear or I'm wrong on something.
Thanks!

Comment: You need mod_rewrite, see some examples: http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite - one of examples solves your problem -> index.php page with page parameter...

Comment: Great! Following your link I was able to satisfy my request! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the link suggested by @nevermind I solved the issue. Below the solution...

1. I created a .htaccess file with inside the following code:

> RewriteEngine on 
>   RewriteRule ^page/([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]

2. I created an index.php file with the following code:

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Test Page</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <?php include $_GET['page'].'.php'; ?>
   </body>
</html>
```

3. I uploaded the two files in the same folder (/test/) together with the file "introduction.php".
4. Considering I wanted to open the page "introduction.php" I pasted the following URL in the browser:

http://www.example.com/page/test/introduction

That's all! Thanks guys for your support. I hope this can help other users looking for the same solution.

Answer (score 0):

page#.php will have to be like this:

```
 <?php 
   include_once('header.php');
   include_once('menu.php');
   //body content of page#
   include_once('footer.php');
 ?>
```

you will still have 3 files with the same url but the header ,footer and menu will be the same across the pages

Comment: This is what I'm already doing but it's not what I'm asking for... Maybe my request isn't so clear.

Comment: you want to map the urls to the php files?

Comment: I want to have just an index.php file to which I can attach the content of page1.php, page2.php, page3.php. The output url should be example.com/page1, example.com/page2, example.com/page3 and not example.com/index.php. So, if I go to example.com/page1 the script should load the page1.php content inside the index.php file...If I go to example.com/page2 the script should load the page2.php content inside the index.php file

Comment: you need as @nevermind sugested mod_rewrite, i sugest you use a php framework(laravel  (see:routes)) to achive the desired efect without you needing to dive in mod_rewrite

Comment: Yes', I've done in this way :) What he suggested works perfect. Thanks for your support